# What do hostPID and hostIPC options mean in a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes pod yaml specification file, you can set a pod to use the host machine's network using `hostNetwork:true`.

I can't find anywhere a good (suitable for a beginner) explanation of what the `hostPID:true` and `hostIPC:true` options mean. Please could someone explain this, assuming little knowledge in linux networking and such. Thanks.

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: podName
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      hostIPC: true
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
```

Source: [github link here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/newrelic/newrelic-daemonset.yaml)

Answer (score 13):

they're roughly described within the [Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces)

> `hostPID` - Use the host’s pid namespace. Optional: Default to false.
>
> `hostIPC` - Use the host’s ipc namespace. Optional: Default to false.

Those are related to the `SecurityContext` of the `Pod`. You'll find some more information in the [Pod Security design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/auth/pod-security-context.md).

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other on SO solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: The link to that design document has changed -- it is now [located here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/auth/pod-security-context.md)

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing the host’s IPC namespace allows container processes to communicate with processes on the host**

source: https://kubesec.io/basics/spec-hostipc/