# Creating a sibling process to a container using containerd

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, weave, containerd

I have a Kubernetes cluster (Docker and containerd) where I deployed the [Weave CNI plugin](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave).

When inspecting the master node processes (`ps -aef --forest`) I can see that the `containerd-shim` process that runs the weave plugin has 3 processes in it's tree:

```
31175  16241 \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/836489.. -address /run/containerd/contai
31199  31175 |   \_ /bin/sh /home/weave/launch.sh
31424  31199 |   |   \_ /home/weave/weaver --port=6783 --datapath=datapath --name=36:e4:33:8
31656  31175 |   \_ /home/weave/kube-utils -run-reclaim-daemon -node-name=ubuntu -peer-name=36:e4
```

What I fail to understand is how the `kube-utils` process (pid 31656), which is issued from the `launch.sh` script process (pid 31199) **is a sibling process of it and not a child process?**

I have tried to create a similar environment to emulate this scenario, by creating a docker image from the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ADD ./launch.sh /home/temp/
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/temp/launch.sh"]
```

Where `launch.sh` in my case is similar in the idea to [that of weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/master/prog/weave-kube/launch.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

start() {
    sleep 2000&
}

start &

sleep 4000
```

After deploying this to the cluster I get the following process tree:

```
114944  16241 \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/d9a6904 -address /run/containerd/contai
114972 114944     \_ /bin/sh /home/temp/launch.sh
115002 114972         \_ sleep 4000
115003 114972         \_ sleep 2000
```

And you can see that both processes are children of the main container process and not a sibling.

**According to the weave scenario above, I would expect that the `sleep 2000` process would be a sibling to the `launch.sh` process and not a child.**

Any idea how to explain the weave situation above? how can I reproduce this locally? or in what scenario is a sibling process created to the container process?

Thank you all.

Comment: Probably `kube-utils` daemonizes itself (via double fork) and then gets reparented by `containerd-shim` as the shim process registers itself as a subreaper. Consider reading something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250153/what-is-a-subreaper-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the weave scenario above, I would expect that the sleep 2000 process would be a sibling to the launch.sh process and not a child.

I reproduced the setup you were having and encountered similar situation (one of the `sleep` command was not a sibling to `launch.sh`). To achieve that you will need following parameters in your `Deployment` or `Pod` YAML:

- `hostPid`
- ```
  securityContext: 
    privileged: true
  ```

You can read more about `hostPid` here:

- *[Medium.com: Limiting pod privileges](https://medium.com/@chrispisano/limiting-pod-privileges-hostpid-57ce07b05896)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: What do hostpid and hostipc options mean in a kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977957/what-do-hostpid-and-hostipc-options-mean-in-a-kubernetes-pod)*

You can read more about `securityContext` here:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Configure pod container: Security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)*

---

It's working with `Weave` as it's having parameters mentioned above. You can look them up here:

- *[Github.com: Weaveworks: weave-daemonset-k8s-1.11.yaml](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/master/prog/weave-kube/weave-daemonset-k8s-1.11.yaml#L180)* :

  - line `141`
  - line `172`
  - line `180`

Also this processes are running by:

- *[Github.com: Weaveworks: weave-kube: launch.sh: Line 186](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/master/prog/weave-kube/launch.sh#L186)*

---

### Example

This is an example to show how you can have a setup where the `sleep` command will be a sibling to `launch.sh`.

The process can differ:

- using `ConfigMap` with a script as an entrypoint
- building an image with all the files included

`launch.sh` file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
start() {
    sleep 10030 &
}
start &
( sleep 10040 &)
sleep 10050 &
/bin/sh -c 'sleep 10060'
```

#### Using `ConfigMap` with a script as an entrypoint

You can use above script to create a `configMap` which will be used to run a pod:

- `$ kubectl create cm --from-file=launch.sh`

`Pod` YAML definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: bashtest
  name: bashtest
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu
    name: bashtest
    command: ["/mnt/launch.sh"]
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
       privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/launch.sh
      name: ep
      subPath: launch.sh
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  hostPID: true
  volumes:
    - name: ep
      configMap:
        defaultMode: 0750
        items:
        - key: launch.sh
          path: launch.sh
        name: entrypoint
```

#### Building an image with all the files included

You can also build an image. Please remember that this image is only for **example purposes**.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ADD ./launch.sh /
RUN chmod 777 ./launch.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/launch.sh"]
```

`Pod` YAML definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: process
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/dkruk-test-00/bashtest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: ubuntu
    securityContext:
       privileged: true
  hostPID: true
  restartPolicy: Always
```

---

After applying the manifest for this resources (either with built image or with a `ConfigMap`), you should be able to run (on a node that is running this `Pod`):

- `$ ps -aef --forest`

and see the output similar to this (only part):

```sh
root     2297272     290  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00  \_ containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/5c802039033683464d5a586
root     2297289 2297272  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      \_ /bin/bash /launch.sh
root     2297306 2297289  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      |   \_ sleep 10050
root     2297307 2297289  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      |   \_ /bin/sh -c sleep 10060
root     2297310 2297307  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      |       \_ sleep 10060
root     2297305 2297272  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      \_ sleep 10040
root     2297308 2297272  0 09:44 ?        00:00:00      \_ sleep 10030
```